# Using firebase github module source since cloud.google.com/go/firestore is not up to date

Tags: firebase, go, build, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using fuego (https://github.com/sgarciac/fuego) which relies on `cloud.google.com/go/firestore` to be able to insert records.

The problem is they changed the auto ID generation here ( https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1715 ) which has caused all kinds of issues, including generating IDs that start with hyphens, and long IDs that are not consistent at all with any other libraries!

As you can see in the GitHub issue it's been resolved, but I don't know enough about Go to be able to figure out how to build fuego using the source from github.

I have no problem building `fuego` from source, but can't figure out how i would build a library it depends on from the source.

When I try to build with it from `github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go` i get an error that the module defines itself as `cloud.google.com/go/firestore`

Can anybody please help me on how i would be able to build it from the github source?  I'm a full time developer .. but not a Go developer, and can't seem to figure it out.

https://github.com/sgarciac/fuego/blob/master/go.mod
https://github.com/sgarciac/fuego/blob/master/add.go

Comment: I do not know GO as well, but I am interested... Tired to figure it out, but I haven't found this "github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/firestore' are you sure this is proper link?

Comment: Yeah it would be for using in Go (it's just a directory in the main repo) i updated it to reflect the actual repo accessible via URL